# call WPF form from another form in C#

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I am working on C# project using WPF.I am trying to call the FPF form from a C# form but   its not opening the WPF Form. I am using the following code to call WPF form .

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        newForm = new MainWindow();

        newForm.Show();
    }
```

Comment: I tried the same code and it worked perfectly. Otherwise you can create a WPF control instead of a form, put that one as a child of ElementHost (WinForm control). The element host is then a child of a regular windows form on which you can call form.Show()

Comment: @Matthias I don't think this is related to winforms. the button seems to be a WPF button (because of the `RoutedEventArgs`. The problem is the lexicon (he's calling a WPF Window a 'form', which it is not).

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I oversaw the RoutedEventArgs. But then I don't understand the problem. Let's see ...